# Do Sonarqube and Whitehat have an available integration?

Tags: sonarqube

We are evaluating replacing HP's Fortify with another tool.  Whitehat came up and we are looking into it but we also use Sonarqube, which integrates the Fortify results into one reporting location.

Does Sonarqube do the same for Whitehat reports?  Seems not, but thought I'd ask the forum......

Any feedback is appreciated.
Thanks,  :-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - at the time being, there's no such integration.